# Is there a commonly used phrase for something being easier with niceness rather than by being forceful?

Tags: phrase-requests

I’m trying to think of a phrase which means that being nice to people can be a better way than to be horrible and forceful to people. Can someone help me out?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39619/origin-and-meaning-of-you-catch-more-flies-with-honey-than-you-do-with-vinegar/70496

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin Good catch, but you'll probably scoop the jackpot if you post that here as an 'answer'. If that would be useful (or if you're bothered).

Answer (score 6):

The phrase you are looking for is “You can catch more flies with honey than you can with vinegar” and it was the subject of [a previous question here on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39619/origin-and-meaning-of-you-catch-more-flies-with-honey-than-you-do-with-vinegar/70496).

Answer (score 1):

"You catch more flies with honey than with vinegar…"

or

"A soft answer turneth away wrath: but grievous words stir up anger." [Proverbs 15:1]

I'm not religious BTW

Mac

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the carrot works better than the stick.

> **carrot and stick**.
>   COMMON If someone uses a carrot and stick method to make you do something, they try to make you do it, partly by offering you rewards and partly by threatening you. 
>   [...] 
>   **Note: Carrot and stick are used in many other structures with a similar meaning.**
>   *Protests continued, however, so the authorities substituted the carrot for the stick. When the Security Council waves a stick at an offending country, the secretary-general can also offer a carrot as encouragement.*
>   Note: The idea behind this expression is that an animal such as a donkey can be encouraged to move forward either by dangling a carrot in front of it or by hitting it with a stick. The carrot represents the tempting offer and the stick represents the threat.
>   [Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary, 3rd ed.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+carrot+and+stick) © HarperCollins Publishers 2012

Answer (score 0):

A fairly well known idiom is **' the softly, softly approach'**.

> An interview with Ivana Trump on Good Morning Britain has raised a few eyebrows after the normally combative Piers Morgan adopted **a softly-softly approach** to questioning.

[Huffington Post 15th January 2018](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/ivana-trump-interview-gmb_uk_5a5c937ee4b03c4189677374)

---

The original expression was '[softly, softly catchee monkey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/softly,_softly,_catchee_monkey)' coined in the late nineteenth century, meaning :

> Proceed cautiously or gently to achieve an objective.

---

But the simplified expression seems to have a wider usage and a broader scope :

> (British English, informal) a/**the gentle, patient and careful way of doing something, especially when dealing with people**: The police are now trying a more softly-softly approach with football

[Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/softly-softly+approach)

---

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=softly+softly%2C+catchee+monkey&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoftly%20softly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatchee%20monkey%3B%2Cc0) of 'softly, softly' against 'catchee monkey' shows that the shortened expression is far more common.

It also seems to be more common in BrE than AmE.

---

Answer (score 0):

> Bill has become so sensitive. You really have to [handle him with kid gloves](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/handle+with+kid+gloves).

Also, **treat with kid gloves**.

Seems to be the opposite of:

> [Handle without mittens (or gloves)](https://archive.org/details/englishidioms00dixouoft): to treat without any superfluous politeness or gentleness; to attack vigorously [with example given from the North American Review, 1887]

The latter is apparently the origin of [gloves are off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gloves+are+off).